# How to solve recurrence equation using RSolve?

Tags: equation-solving, series-expansion, difference-equations

How can I solve the following recurrence equation while I dont have the initial values?
Is it possible to solve this using RSolve?

```
-I (w+k x+2n y+m(x-2y)+l(x+2y)) u[w+k x+2n y+m(x-2y)+l(x+2y)] == A0 u[w+k x+2n y+m(x-2y)+l(x+2y)] + A1 u[w+k x+2(n+1) y+m(x-2y)+l(x+2y)]+ A2 u[w+k x+2(n-1) y+m(x-2y)+l(x+2y)] + A3 u[w+(k+1) x+2n y+m(x-2y)+l(x+2y)] + A4 u[w+(k-1) x+2n y+m(x-2y)+l(x+2y)] + A5 u[w+(k+1) x+(2n+1) y+m(x-2y)+l(x+2y)] + A6 u[w+(k-1) x+(2n-1) y+m(x-2y)+l(x+2y)] + A7 u[w+(k-1) x+(2n+1) y+m(x-2y)+l(x+2y)]+ A8 u[w+(k+1) x+(2n-1) y+m(x-2y)+l(x+2y)] + s[w+k x+2n y+m(x-2y)+l(x+2y)]
```

In this equation, k, n, m, l= ...,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,...
u and s are two functions. x, y, A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7 and A8 are fixed parameters.

How the following command can be useful to get the correct result?

```
RSolve[-I (w + k x + 2 n y + m (x - 2 y) + l (x + 2 y)) u[
    w + k x + 2 n y + m (x - 2 y) + l (x + 2 y)] == 
  A0 u[w + k x + 2 n y + m (x - 2 y) + l (x + 2 y)] + 
   A1 u[w + k x + 2 (n + 1) y + m (x - 2 y) + l (x + 2 y)] + 
   A2 u[w + k x + 2 (n - 1) y + m (x - 2 y) + l (x + 2 y)] + 
   A3 u[w + (k + 1) x + 2 n y + m (x - 2 y) + l (x + 2 y)] + 
   A4 u[w + (k - 1) x + 2 n y + m (x - 2 y) + l (x + 2 y)] + 
   A5 u[w + (k + 1) x + (2 n + 1) y + m (x - 2 y) + l (x + 2 y)] + 
   A6 u[w + (k - 1) x + (2 n - 1) y + m (x - 2 y) + l (x + 2 y)] + 
   A7 u[w + (k - 1) x + (2 n + 1) y + m (x - 2 y) + l (x + 2 y)] + 
   A8 u[w + (k + 1) x + (2 n - 1) y + m (x - 2 y) + l (x + 2 y)] + 
   s[w + k x + 2 n y + m (x - 2 y) + l (x + 2 y)], u, w]
```

Comment: You claim that "n=...-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,..." and then "n is a function". Which is it? Usually recurrence equations are things like `x[t]==3*x[t-1]` so what is your recurrence variable like `t` in this?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the equation. Now, u and s are two functions. In my equation,  the recurrence variable is "w".

Comment: Should `...+A6 u[w(k-1) x+...` be `...A6 u[w+(k-1) x+...` If so then all your expressions appear to be `u[w+constant]` and do not see how to write this in the form `u[w+1]==u[w]+expression`. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct. But it is important to see the behaviour of functions u and s in terms of x and y.

Comment: This sexample hould be put in to copy-pastable Mathematica format.

Comment: The example is in a copy-pastable Mathematical format. I have used the RSolve command, but received no results!